# How to style content of pages without adding css class to element?

Tags: css, xhtml

I use CMS for client and client doesn't know CSS he use WYSIWYG editor to put content in pages. Client adds Paragraphs, images, images in paragraph (left or right floated), ordered and unordered list, Tables. Problems comes when he want to add images in paragraph (left or right floated). and without adding css class it's not possible. And i don't want to add `<div>` in content because WYSIWYG editor can't manage div and client works in WYSIWYG mode.

How to style content of pages without using css class?

Comment: You could try using tables to enforce position. Not my preferred method, but seeing as you can't use classes...

Comment: yes i use table but i asked if there any other css way to do this

Comment: Can you please post sample HTML with images you try to position with stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

You will need your user to add a CSS class/style attribute to the image somehow - *without adding something to the image to tell it to float right or left it won't float right or left.*

If your question is how the client can add the class without having to manually edit the HTML I reckon the only way is to dive into the WYSIWYG editor's javascript and write something a bit like this towards the end of the image-adding process:

```js
var alignment = prompt("Type l to align the picture to the left, and r to align the picture to the right","l").strToLower();
if(alignment == 'r')
{
  //line of code to add class "right" to the image tag
} else {
  //line of code to add class "left" to the image tag
}
```

What the code to add the classes should depend on how the WYSIWYG editor works

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [element selectors](http://www.eskimo.com/~bloo/indexdot/css/syntax/selectors/element.htm) or [ID selectors](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php) to add styles to HTML elements without referencing CSS class in them.

Element selector would add border to all images on the page:

```
img { border:1px; }
```

ID selector would do the same only to image with ID 'image1':

```
img #image1 { border:1px; }
```

Still you will need to reference the stylesheet from your page.

Comment: yes but how to make float right and left possible without adding class

Comment: same element sometime can be left align and on different place on same page that element needed in right align, that is the problem

Comment: img {float: right; }

Works for me in a quick sample. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do images have different IDs?

Comment: I know but what if on same page we need one image in on right and one in left?

Comment: If there is a way to distinguish images, e.g. through their IDs or IDs of parents, you will be able to assign required style with selectors.

Comment: if you are not getting my question then i can make image to describe u

Comment: How is your WYSIWYG editor aligning them? Wordpress, for example, appends classes to the IMG tags. If you look at the HTML output, you can figure out how to cater your CSS to select them.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways you can make [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html) that don't require CSS classes.  For example, to make a rule that applies to all img tags inside p tags, you could write this:

```
p img { float: left; }
```

But how are you hoping to determine which images need to be right-aligned and which images need to be left aligned?  Does that data exist in the document in any machine readable format?

Comment: I know but what if on same page we need one image in on right and one in left?

Answer (score 0):

A WYSWYG should have "align" property for an image (at least those I have seen). You can then use CSS attribute selector `img [align=left] { float:left; }` or `img [align=right] {float:right;}` This wont work on IE 6,7 though, you can use JavaScript to mimic this for those browsers.